# Jenkins: Loading library conditionally

Tags: git, jenkins, shared-libraries

I am using Jenkins and using a shared library for several repositories. 
Sometimes, I start a development branch in the library, associated to a development branch in a repository.

I am trying to achieve the following:

- In the jenkinsfile of the repository using the library
- If a branch of the same name than the current branch exist in the shared library repository, then checkout this version of the library
- Else, checkout the default version

Which looks like this:

```
def library

try{
    library = library("foolib@" + this.env.BRANCH_NAME)
    echo "Perfectly loaded library"
}
catch(err){
    echo "Error loading library"
    library = library("foolib") //Error occurs here
}
```

However this is failling with the following:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method call() on null object

I am already doing something like this, in the jenkins file of the library actually:

def lib = library("foolib@${env.BRANCH_NAME}")

And it is working perfectly fine. I just need to use this in a conditional statement (hence, a try catch since I have no easy way to know if the branch exist or not)

Can I solve this ?

Comment: You can define the same library in the Jenkins settings with multiple branches (version) or allow to overwrite the version

Comment: Well I do not know the branch in advance so I really need it to be dynamic

Comment: Then you could define the library with one "main version" (e.g. "master") and allow to overwrite it.

Comment: Well, I am already doing that. What I need is a conditional statement:

IF CurrentBranch exists in Library repository THEN load this branch
ELSE load master branch

Currently what I have to do is to change manually, in the jenkins file, which branch I load.